# User cannot download data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I've created app using `ionic`.
App downloads data from my `api`.

App is working but one user (out of few hundered) has problem with it. App is not downloading any data. He tried on two different networks. When he opens direct url of that api data is downloaded.

I know that we have very little information, but maybe someone had the same problem?

App was built with `ionic-angular: ^3.9.2`
He uses android 6.0 and `S2` smartphone.

Comment: Are you using https? Does the user have the hour and date correctly configured in his phone? (yeah, sounds silly, but can cause problems)

Comment: I'm using https... Date and hour can cause problems?

Comment: Yeah, it can. Here you can read other possible solutions https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/fix-ssl-connection-errors-android-phones/